# I want the length 3 words on alphabet {0,1,2} with no two consecutive 1's

Tags: list-manipulation

I tried this code but it doesn't work. DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3], {**_ 1, 1, _**}].

Comment: Try replacing `_` with `___` (i.e. three underscores rather than one). Also, you have a missing comma. So: `{___, 1, 1, ___}`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I did use 3 underscores.  I have just now realized that I am missing a comma (before the first 1) in my code.  However I am still curios what Mathematica is doing with DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3], {_ 1, 1, _}] where the comma is missing.

Comment: Where the comma is missing? I think it multiples `Blank` (which is `_`) by 1, resulting in `_`. So you were trying to delete all cases that match `{_, 1, _}`, i.e. all triples with 1 in the center spot. By the way, the three underscores matches any sequence of 0, 1, or more elements. This makes it so that you can match, for instance, `{1,1,0}`.

Comment: Errrr ... Not recommended `Select[{{##} + 1, #1^#2  #2^#3} & @@@ (Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3] - 1) // 
   Quiet, Last@# =!= Indeterminate &][[All, 1]]`

Comment: If you ever expand past 3, you can use `Repeated` as so: `DeleteCases[
 Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 4], {___, Repeated[1, {2, Infinity}], ___}]`

Comment: Also not recommended, but using pattern matching `Cases[{{##} + 1, #1^#2  #2^#3} & @@@ (Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3] - 1) // 
  Quiet, {x_, y : Except[Indeterminate]} :> x]`

Comment: @belisarius. It seems I've been chastised. What will happen?

Comment: @march By whom?When?Where?Why?

Comment: @belisarius. I thought your comment was directed at me, and that the `___` solution was not recommended, and so the "What will happen?" was in reference to why `___` is not a recommended solution. (The "I've been chastised" was meant to be flippant.)

Comment: @march Oh,no.Your solution is Ok. Mine was intended as a joke so it's "not recommended". I was abusing a nuisance of Mma ( `0^0` returns `Indeterminate`). Sorry for the confusion. However, Perhaps a good non-pattern-matching solution could be in order

Comment: @belisarius Got it. I fall into pits all the time, so I assumed there was something I was missing. My go-to solutions usually involve pattern-matching, but I'll think on a direct solution.

Comment: @march A half-witted one ;) `(({Abs[Times @@ (1 - Times @@ Partition[#, 2, 1])], #} & /@ 
        Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3] // Sort // SplitBy[#, First] &) // 
    Rest)[[All, All, 2]] // Flatten[#, 1] &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given my simple but sane mind (unlike belisarius who has a brilliant but twisted one), I would solve your problem by modifying your code just a bit.

```
DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3], {1, 1, _} | {_, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, 
>  {0, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0}, 
>  {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 0}, 
>  {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
> ```

This works because in this problem, for two ones to appear consecutively, they must be in the 1st two slots or (inclusively) the 2nd two slots. I think this should be a little faster than using `___`, but it doesn't matter much with your very small alphabet.